Azure WebApp autoscale
Do we have an option to create an auto-scale settings for multiple webapps attached to a single app service plan? If yes, please share on how to do this.
For Ex:
Day 1 - Creating WebAppA attached to appsvcplan1 and creating and attaching autoscale1 to it  Based on number of requests received (It works fine).
Day 2 - Creating WebAppB attached to appsvcplan1, but not sure on how to create an autoscale setting and attach to it.
I have tried searching in internet, couldn't able to find a proper solution.

An appservice plan autoscale settings can accommodate more than one app service. This can be configured under single profile and maximum of ten rules per profile and at a time only one profile will be in use.
For Ex:
Appservice Plan - Compute Metric rule - 2(scale up and scale down)
Appservices     - No.Of Requests rule - 8 (4 appservice * 2 rules (scale up and down)) can be configured.

When you scale out, you scale the App Service Plan, not an individual App Service (Web  App). During scaling, Azure creates a new Plan (under the hood - a Virtual Machine) that runs your web app(s).
You mentioned you have an App Plan with autoscale settings and one App Service. If you add a new app service to the same plan, it will be covered automatically.
Below is an example of bicep code. planId and planName variables are id and name of the App Service Plan, respectively.
resource autoscale 'Microsoft.Insights/autoscalesettings@2022-10-01' = {
  name: 'autoscale-${planName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    name: 'autoscale-${planName}'
    targetResourceUri: planId
    targetResourceLocation: location
    profiles: [
      {
        name: 'autoscale-profile-${planName}'
        capacity: {
         ...
        }
        rules: [
         ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Thanks @Artem, for your answer. So it is one auto-scale settings and multiple profiles. Am I right. If I have configured appservice autoscale settings based on no.of requests received. It may vary from each appservice to appservice. But here, if it automatically enabled based on first appservice not sure how effectively it works.

Are you referring to Automatic Autoscale?

Yes, your understanding is correct. In Azure App Service, autoscale settings are configured at the App Service Plan level, and you can define multiple autoscale profiles within a single autoscale setting. @Dilly B
enter link description here

Thanks for your reply. Yes, I was able to add multiple app services under one appservice plan profile. Also, there is a limitation of 10 rules (a pair of each rule) per autoscaling profile. I did this using Terraform.
